# How could I use TensorFlow in jupyter notebook? I install TensorFlow via python 3.5 pip already

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, installation, jupyter-notebook

I installed tensorflow via python3.5 pip, it is in the python3.5 lib folder and I can use it perfectly on shell IDLE.

I have anaconda(jupyter notebook) on my computer at the same time, however, I couldn't import tensorflow on notebook.

I guess notebook was using the anaconda lib folder, not python3.5 libs. is there any way to fix that instead of install again on anaconda folder?

thanks

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Have you tried going through my below answer? I have this exact set up. Conda with python 3.5 using Windows 10 64-bit and jupyter notebooks is fine! I can probably help you through this. See how the answer below goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package called **nb_conda** that helps manage your anaconda kernels. However, when you launch Jupyter make sure that you have jupyter installed inside your conda environment and that you are launching Jupyter from that activated environment.

So:

- Activate your conda environment that has Tensorflow installed. You can check by doing `conda list`. If Tensorflow is not installed **within** your environment then do so.
- Install jupyter and nb_conda if you haven't already.
- From your activated environment, run jupyter notebook.
- You should now be running in the correct kernel. You should see a kernel named `Python [conda env:namehere]` in the top right. You may also have a choice of kernels thanks to nb_conda if installed.

See if that works for you.

Comment: Hi, I installed anaconda at the very first, and used the jupyter notebook inside anaconda on http://localhost:8888.......... I checked the conda list on anconda prompt windows, there's no tensorflow package installed. I am bit confused the following steps you told me.

Comment: where could I find the nb_conda?

Comment: Please make sure you understand how Anaconda works and you **must** activate your environment. Once inside your environment install Tensorflow using pip install tensorflow. Then install jupyter and install nb_conda. I think it's available from conda install. nb_conda is not required but may make your life easier. That should work if you follow the steps. You MUST be inside your environment.You will know because your command prompt will look like (envName) C:/... instead of just C:/...